# A board or mat that we can detect a push at an exact point

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

Is there any kind of board or mat that when we place it on the floor and wire it, a self-made connected device can read these data when it is being pushed and holding onto it, at multiple points?

- Location where the force is applied onto. Something working similar to a touchscreen, or a trackpad, or at least a keyboard. Except it's not any of those :-D
- Magnitude of the force

I need to build a footstep detecting device consisting a board that can be wired and detect point of pressure and how much amount it is. It is something working like a capacitive sensing device. But able to handle greater pressure.

Comment: Define "exact point"? Pin point, thumb print, foot print....

Comment: In my case it is foot print

Comment: So, update your question making that clear, also what needs to be detected - the footprint, the precise area, the contact outline, the highest pressure points...

Comment: updated. i'll update again if insufficient of info

Comment: The more clearly and precisely you define the question, the better, so give all the relevant detail you can so people don’t waste their time...

Comment: Look into load cells - imagine a grid made of digital bathroom scales. The actual sensing unit is small and you could size it to be a few cm square for each detection point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Pressure sensing mats.

They are used for exactly what you want to use them for, getting stepped on for footprint and gait analysis.